# Extracting types and returning a mapped tuple type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm having issues with a mapped type converting to a union-type array rather than a tuple type.

I'm seeing an error that indicates that `fn` expects a signature of

`'(...values: (string | boolean)[]) => void'` vs my preferred
`'(a: string, b: boolean) => void'`

It's likely my misunderstanding [of this change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063), but is there something missing that would type `RawValues<T>` to a tuple rather than a union-type array to allow me to strongly type the arguments of the `fn` I pass in?

Thanks!

```
type ValueType<T> = {  value: T; };
type RawValue<T> = T extends ValueType<infer U> ? U : never;
type RawValues<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: RawValue<T[P]>;
};
function extractAndRun<T extends ValueType<any>[]>(values: T, fn: (...values: RawValues<T>) => void): RawValues<T> {
    const rawValues = values.map((val) => val.value) as RawValues<T>;
    fn(...rawValues);
    return rawValues;
}

const result = extractAndRun(
  [{value: 'string'}, {value: true}],
  // PROBLEM IS HERE. See error message in code block below.
  (a: string, b: boolean) => {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
  });
console.log(result); // ['string', true]
```

```
    Argument of type '(a: string, b: boolean) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...values: (string | boolean)[]) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'a' and 'values' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    'b' is declared but its value is never read.
```

[TS Playground here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Typescript weakens the type of your tuple to an array of unions, before it is used to infer `T`. There are two solutions: either ensure that the type is not weakened by using `as const`, or have a generic type which is inferred from the callback function's parameters instead of the array.

Solution 1: the upper bound of `T` is `readonly` to accommodate the `as const` assertion, and `RawValues` removes this modifier. Note that the result is inferred with literal types as `['string', true]` instead of `[string, boolean]`.

```
type RawValues<T> = {
    -readonly [P in keyof T]: RawValue<T[P]>;
};

function extractAndRun<T extends readonly ValueType<any>[]>(values: T, fn: (...values: RawValues<T>) => void): RawValues<T> {
    const rawValues = values.map((val: any) => val.value) as RawValues<T>;
    fn(...rawValues);
    return rawValues;
}

const result = extractAndRun([{value: 'string'}, {value: true}] as const, (a: string, b: boolean) => {
    // ...
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrggHlQPigXigG8ooA3RFALilQG4oBfOgKFEigCU4B3eZLLgK0oEAB7AIAOwAmAZ1iU0GTAEspAMwgAnKAFU8Afn1QaUiGR2t20bnyVzseQkRalSAWm0Q4MgPZSCCBQANoAClDqUADWECB+GrQAujR2-CjY4Uk4rMwsLBpIUgDGwKoBohLacKUAgrKcRdiVkrIK3r4BQYoC6JCYcFIgOCHZABQUAnI0qAA0UBpSNGMAdGuTKNNcvOkQjrgAlAR4ZH6qMgepOw5OxG7uxQFywFDV9lPCG3srALZwYGMJogaIMQEd8CdECsvkc4Ao0jdcKx3AspKs1m9dnIDsj3N5gEhtFJXtcprl8o8pM9XnskAgXoRxMBqnUGkUxiEiF8aAByZ7adQAcx5jHmXKUNGZKEYSSgcKglOe8zGcBo-KF8wARjRNX4-AgfFJwXhXKRFfqICsEH5BSqcaR7uaDVabWNNTiWIwPU7Ldbbd45HTgB6gA)

Solution 2: `T` will be the array of raw values, so the `WrappedValues` type transforms it into the required tuple type.

```
type WrappedValues<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer A, ...infer B] ? [ValueType<A>, ...WrappedValues<B>] : []

function extractAndRun<T extends any[]>(values: WrappedValues<T>, fn: (...values: T) => void): T {
    const rawValues = values.map((val: any) => val.value) as T;
    // ...
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrggHlQPigXigG8ooA3RFALilQG4oBfOgKFEigHUAnOMSACbxkEAM7YoEAB7AIAOwGiocOSADaAXTyFUkmfMVQ1ASzkAzCNygBBADRQAdE9MWrAIQ1QA-EeEp0kJjWOPZODjx8gn5imG44njSaLCxmSHIAxsDGAPZyesC8mdYKAEppEtKyCkoq6loAFBQiojQR-BBClDG49mZyNPVhTSgttACUBHhk2cYCYzS6RCykpOm5osBQvADu0UqEw2IOALZ89Y2INLUT+FOIDocTcEr0yyt9g047e2OsK1sQYBIbh5b5dUSsRjJNZyDYA0RIBCbQiVQrAYoCMpyepqIiHGgAcg23FMAHMCYx7HiujQCihGBp7PU4DRiWT7AAjGgc7LZBAQFQ3PBLVbrPkQBwIbKk5m-UhvGGicWS6X1Dm-FiMDWK5VSmXcMSI4AaoA)

Comment: awesome, thank you for the solutions! FYI looks like adding in the `Readonly<T>` modifier is enough even without the `as const` assertion. I hadn't considered your solution 2, but I think that may be more readable. thanks again!

Comment: @megabits Ah, that means I did it wrong, because `as const` should definitely be needed - and indeed, I did it wrong, it was giving `any[]`. Edited to fix.

Comment: "ensure that the type is not weakened by using `as const`" saved my day! What that means is: when you define a tuple, write `as const` after it to prevent typescript from weakening each elements' type to a union of all of the types present in the array. This ensures each index of the array remains typed by its contents i.e. is associated with a specific type.